# String method to change particular element in Scala

Tags: string, list, scala, overriding

I need to write a method in Scala that overrides the toString method. I wrote it but I also have to check that if there is an element that is '1' I will change it to 'a', else write the list as it is with the string method. Any suggestions how this can be done?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what class are you taking? If this is a beginner's course in programming, it seems to have a too steep curve.

Comment: yes it is a beginner course in functional programming and scala

Comment: It's time to get beyond the one-liner.  Break this up into multiple vals or defs so that you can see where the problem is. Off-hand, I think the second "list" needs to be left out.  Remember, `map` doesn't change the original list - it makes a new one.  Also, I suspect, from the error, that you are being given a list of lists, but you're not sharing enough to tell for sure.

Comment: yes I am give a list of lists... what is the problem that needs to be changed because of that? thanks a lotttt

Comment: You can convert a string to a list of chars. Then recurse over it replacing the the right characters. then turn it back into a string and return it. Nothing more need be done.

Comment: can you give an example in code? does mine require small changes or it is totally wrong? I am really new to scala and I need to practice and know why it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? seems to work for me

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)
println(this)

override def toString(): String = {
  val t = l.map({
    case 1 => "a"
    case x => x
  })
  t.toString
}
```

getting `List(a, 2, 3)` printed out

Answer (score 0):

I see from the comments on your question that `list` is a `List[List[Int]]`.

Look at the beginning of your code:

```
list.map { case 1 => 'a'; case x => x}
```

`map` expects a function that takes an element of `list` as a parameter - a `List[Int]`, in your case. But your code works directly on `Int`.

With this information, it appears that the error you get is entirely correct: you declared a method that expects an `Int`, but you pass a `List[Int]` to it, which is indeed a type mismatch.

Try this:

```
list.map {_.map { case 1 => 'a'; case x => x}}
```

This way, the function you defined to transform 1 to a and leave everything else alone is applied to `list`'s sublists, and this type-checks: you're applying a function that expects an `Int` to an `Int`.